# ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset L does not exist

Tags: arcpy, loop, error-000732

I am trying to create a loop so that each layer is produced in its own map.

This is my code:

```
import arcpy
path = "C:\Users\Et\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path +"\WinterGritting.mxd")
df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyrList =arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df)[0].name
elements=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements (mxd)
for eachlyr in lyrList:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(eachlyr,'NEW_SELECTION')
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures() 
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(eachlyr,'CLEAR_SELECTION')
    mxd.title=eachlyr.name
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, path + "\Routes" + eachlyr.name + "jpg")

del mxd
```

The Error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Et/Documents/Python", line 9, in 
>       arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(eachlyr,'NEW_SELECTION')   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6494, in
>   SelectLayerByAttribute
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset L does not exist or is
>   not supported Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different way to do this by setting the dataframe equal to the current layer's extent. It a lot more simple. Also, you'd better check your path because it shows the MXD being inside the geodatabase.

```
import arcpy
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\Et\\Documents\\ArcGIS" #need to use two backslashes
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(path, "WinterGritting.mxd")) #use os.path.join
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
layer_list = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df) #don't use indexing here

for layer in layer_list:
    layer_name = str(layer.name)

    for layer_check in layer_list: #turns on/off other layers
        if layer_check != layer:
           layer_check.visible = False
           layer.visible = True

    mxd.title = layer_name    
    layer_extent = layer.getExtent() #get the extent of the current layer
    df.extent = layer_extent #set the dataframe to the layer's extent
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, os.path.join(path, "Routes", layer_name + ".jpg"))

del mxd
```

---

Updated for comment.

Add the names of whatever layers you don't want to turn off into the landbase list.

```
import arcpy
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\Et\\Documents\\ArcGIS" #need to use two backslashes
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(path, "WinterGritting.mxd")) #use os.path.join
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
layer_list = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df) #don't use indexing here

landbase = ["Roads", "Lakes"] #add layer names you want always visible here

for layer in layer_list:
    layer_name = str(layer.name)

    if layer_name not in landbase:

        for layer_check in layer_list: #turns on/off other layers
            if layer_check != layer and layer_check.name not in landbase:
                layer_check.visible = False
            else:
                layer_check.visible = True

        mxd.title = layer_name
        layer_extent = layer.getExtent() #get the extent of the current layer
        df.extent = layer_extent #set the dataframe to the layer's extent
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, os.path.join(path, "Routes", layer_name + ".jpg"))

del mxd
```

Comment: Hi Thank you very much that is working perfectly now. I just have another query. How do i set a layer (e.g roads) to feature behind all my other layers instead of being produced as a single JPEG.

Comment: @WizTownley I updated my answer.